# DropDownList SelectedIndexChanged event not firing within GridView HeaderTemplate

Tags: gridview, drop-down-menu, selectedindexchanged

I am working on a job board website and specifically the job search page at the moment. I am returning the jobs found into a `DataBound` `GridView` (namely `gvwJobs`), and within the `HeaderTemplate` I have a `DropDownList` named `ddlSortDirection` which specifies the direction in which the sorting is performed:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlSortDirection" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlSortDirection_SelectedIndexChanged">

    <asp:ListItem Value="DESC">DOWN</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="ASC">UP</asp:ListItem>

</asp:DropDownList>
```

As you can see, I have ensured that `AutoPostBack` is on. I have also created a custom event handler on the `GridView`'s `DataBound` event as so:

```
Protected Sub gvwJobs_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvwJobs.RowDataBound

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Header Then

                ddlSortDirection.AutoPostBack = True
                AddHandler ddlSortDirection.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf ddlSortDirection_SelectedIndexChanged


     End If

End Sub
```

I am finding that the `ddlSortDirection_SelectedIndexChanged` SubProcedure is not called when the selection is changed in `ddlSortDirection`. I can see that a `PostBack` occurs, but the method is definitely not called. What I have tried doing is creating a similar `DropDownList` outside of the `GridView` and that successfully triggered the `SelectedIndexChanged` event without even having a custom event handler!

Please could you help me to achieve my goal of having a `DropDownList` firing the `SelectedIndexChanged` event when within a `HeaderTemplate` of a `GridView`?

Answer (score 1):

set the `EnableViewState` of that GridView to false

Answer (score -1):

set `runat="server"` on `DropDownList`

Eg:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSortDirection" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
            onselectedindexchanged="ddlSortDirection_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
```